# How to assign read only permission to file

Tags: java, android, file, file-io, android-file

Hello i want to create one file and write some data in it and after that i want to assign read only permission to that file so no one else will can modify it.

i have done writing part
but i don't have any idea how to set Read only permission and remove other all permissions
i have tried setReadOnly(); but its not working.

please let me know if there is any solution for this.
thank you in advanced...

i have tried following, but its not working

```
String currentDateTimeString;
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss");//date format
            currentDateTimeString = sdf.format(new Date());//current date
            File recordFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "WBS/Record");
            recordFolder.mkdirs(); // <----make a folder
            File file = new File(recordFolder, currentDateTimeString+".xml");//create the images

            File dbtest =new File("/data/data/com/ami/wbs/databases/WBS");

            if(!dbtest.exists())
            {
              // what to do if it does exist
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DB is present", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
              // what to do if it doesn't exist
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DB is not present", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

                database = new DB_Adapter(getApplicationContext(), "WBS", null, 1);
                FileWriter filewrite = null;
                //BufferedWriter filewrite = null;
                try {

                    //filewrite = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(currentDateTimeString+".xml", MODE_PRIVATE)));
                    filewrite = new FileWriter(file,true);
                    filewrite.write("<?xml version='1.0' ?>");
                    filewrite.write("<Resultset>");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                SQLiteDatabase db=database.getReadableDatabase();
                Cursor c = db.rawQuery("Select CONSUMER_ID,METER_NO,PREV_READING,CURR_READING from CONSUMER;", null);

                if(c.moveToNext())
                {
                //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Table found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Table not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                c.moveToFirst();
                do
                {

                    String consumerid=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("CONSUMER_ID"));
                    String meterno=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("METER_NO"));
                    String currentreading=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("CURR_READING"));

                    try {
                        filewrite.write("<consumer>"
                                        +"<consumerid>"+consumerid+"</consumerid>"
                                        +"<meter>"+meterno+"</meter>"
                                         +"<curread>"+currentreading+"</curread></consumer>");
                         filewrite.write("</Resultset>");
                          filewrite.close();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }while(c.moveToNext());
     file.setReadOnly();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Export file successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working' ? Are you getting any errors/exceptions ?

Answer (score 3):

If the file is on internal storage (e.g., `getFilesDir()`), it is read only by default.

If the file is on external storage (e.g., `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`), AFAIK you cannot change the permission bits to make it read only.

Comment: yes its on sdcard in WBS/Record named folder but when i checked permission in ddms its showing that it have all permission read write all

Comment: @YograjShinde: As I wrote, AFAIK you cannot change the permission bits to make it read only. If you want it to be read only, do not put it on external storage.